# R error in get(search()[2]): object not found when trying to call a function from a loaded package

Tags: r

Having a very strange error when trying to use a package downloaded from Cran (epicalc). Some functions from this package work fine, but when I try to call one specific function (followup.plot), I get the following error:

Error in get(search()[2]) : object 'package:epicalc' not found
Calls: followup.plot -> get

Any ideas what this means and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a result of some rather "interesting" code within `followup.plot`

```
if (missing(xlab)) {
    xlab <- as.character(substitute(time))
    if (any(class(get(search()[2])) == "data.frame")) {
        if (any(attr(get(search()[2]), "names") == as.character(substitute(xlab)))) {
            if (!is.null(attr(get(search()[2]), "var.labels")[attr(get(search()[2]), 
              "names") == as.character(substitute(xlab))])) {
              if (attr(get(search()[2]), "var.labels")[attr(get(search()[2]), 
                "names") == as.character(substitute(xlab))] != 
                "") {
                xlab <- attr(get(search()[2]), "var.labels")[attr(get(search()[2]), 
                  "names") == as.character(substitute(xlab))]
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
if (missing(ylab)) {
    ylab <- as.character(substitute(outcome))
    if (any(class(get(search()[2])) == "data.frame")) {
        if (any(attr(get(search()[2]), "names") == as.character(substitute(ylab)))) {
            if (!is.null(attr(get(search()[2]), "var.labels")[attr(get(search()[2]), 
              "names") == as.character(substitute(ylab))])) {
              if (attr(get(search()[2]), "var.labels")[attr(get(search()[2]), 
                "names") == as.character(substitute(ylab))] != 
                "") {
                ylab <- attr(get(search()[2]), "var.labels")[attr(get(search()[2]), 
                  "names") == as.character(substitute(ylab))]
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which assumes you have `attach`ed or `use`d the source of your variables.

This is highly bizarre behaviour to assume (IMHO)

Comment: This does the trick, thanks so much! I agree that is an odd assumption to make.